# Object/Array methods: Modify original or create new? Guidelines

Tags: javascript, object, methods, standards

With javascript we have methods like `filter` and `map` which do not modify the original array, but create a new array based on the supplied function.

We also have methods like `sort` which modify the original array.

The above are examples that are part of ECMA standards.

I also see tailored functions in libraries or GISTs, that do not conform to any standards or best practices.

Things like `shuffle`, often using algorithms like `Fisher–Yates`, which 90% of the time modify the original array but occasionally create a new array.

Methods like `compress` which remove `holes` in arrays, again often modifying the original array, but on occasion creating a new array.

So while investigating `unique` or `removeDuplicates`, I came across 3 possibilities.

```
function unique(array) {
    create newArray;
    push unique values into newArray;
    return newArray;
}
```

The above creates a new array of unique values, leaving the original array intact.

```
function unique(array) {
    remove duplicates from original array;
    return array;
}
```

The above modifies the original array as well as returning the reference to the original.

```
function unique(array) {
    create removedArray;
    remove duplicates from original array and push the removed elements into removedArray;
    return removedArray,
}
```

The above is similar to the previous except that it records the removed elements and returns them to me, kind of like `splice`.

This all got me to wondering if there are any standards or best practices when it comes to creating methods that work on Object or Array?

I haven't found any, do they exist?

If not, then I know this question can lead to opinion based answers, but it seems a sensible question to ask?

Comment: It's when you start messing with the prototypes that you have to be careful. In those three examples you're not doing that.

Comment: Those three examples could equally be applied to `prototype`, and are in some of my investigations. This is why I wonder if there is any standard or best practice?

Comment: there is no best practice.Some say you should never mutate arrays,others say javascript is no pure functional programming language so it makems little difference.Others say object should only be mutated through mutators,every other method should not mutate the object. I say just document whatever the method does or doesnt do

Comment: Documentation is a definite best practice, and I'm guessing the only real answer.

Comment: Wow, a close vote for `too broad`!? That was unexpected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The ECMAScript Language Specification 5.1 (2011)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) doesn't outline *why* some methods modify the original object and why some others do not.

It only outlines, as an example, for `Array.prototype.map` ([15.4.4.19](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.19)) that

> **map** does not directly mutate the object on which it is called but
>   the object may be mutated by the calls to `callbackfn`.

without specifying a reason as to why this is the case.

However, for methods which *do* modify the original object, no special notice seems to be made outside the general description of the method. An example from the definition of `Array.prototype.sort` ([15.4.4.11](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11)):

> The elements of this array are sorted. *[Rest of the definition follows.]*

So to summarize:
In the cases where the original object is *not* modified, an explicit note is made about it, while in the cases where the original object *is* modified no special notice is added. Therefore it seems there is an implied standard that such methods modify the original object, however there is no explicit agreement or specification for it.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable assumption, never thought about that.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to prepare this useful answer.